# How to nest anonymous interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have the following data (received from somewhere) I wanted to describe in an `interface` to hint about types:

```
 {
   forecast: {
     '22': {temp: 28, weather: 800},
     '32': {temp: 21, weather: 500},
     '36': {temp: 19, weather: 803},
     '40': {temp: 23, weather: 804},
     '46': {temp: 22, weather: 804},
   },
   rain: {start: 0, end: 1627063620, heavy_rain: false},
 }
```

In order to do so, I had to create two "helper" interfaces:

```
interface ForecastForecast {
  temp: number,
  weather: number
}

interface ForecastRain {
  start: number,
  end: number,
  heavy_rain: boolean
}

interface ForecastMain {
  forecast: {
    [key: string]: ForecastForecast
  },
  rain: ForecastRain
}

// declaration of my variable in Vue3
let forecast = ref<ForecastMain>({forecast: {}, rain: {start: 0, end: 0, heavy_rain: false}})
```

Since I need neither `ForecastRain` nor `ForecastForecast`, is it possible to simplify the declaration by directly nesting the relevant interfaces? Something like

```
interface Hello {
  name: interface {
    first: string,
    last: string,
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the interfaces `ForecastForecast` and `ForecastRain` on their own elsewhere in your code, you stick to declaring them as interfaces as you did in your example. If you don't, you just specify the expected types inline without giving them a name.

```
interface ForecastMain {
  forecast: {
    [key: string]: {temp: number, weather: number}
  },
  rain: {start: number, end: number, heavy_rain: boolean}
}
```

Declaring an interface inline (as you did in your last code snippet) is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Hello` example, you don't need nested `interface` keyword:

```js
interface Hello {
  name: {
    first: string,
    last: string,
  },
  ...
```